# EventHub SAS token for write not working

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-eventhub

I created a Shared Access Policy within my event hub for a client library that must send events but although it never fails, the events aren't being received by the hub, the only way this is working is when I use the RootSharedAccessKey, but this isn't the way it should happen.

Comment: Look at the end of your endpoint connection string with the keys. Then remove ";EntityPath=myhub;".

Comment: please be more specific: share code snippets of how you tried to send to eventhub in both cases and how did you get to know that eventhub didn't receive the events.
Given, that this is a multi-tenant service running world-wide - & one of the core services on Microsoft Azure & this is a most common scenario; pl. consider the fact that there are chances that - your client-code could have a bug... :)

Answer (score 0):

When you create the Shared Access Key for your client to send to your EventHub, please make sure it should at least have "Send" claim (the other two are "Listen" and "Manage"). You could verify this on Azure Portal in the EventHub configuration page.